# Kendo Grid "Date" formatter "day" of the week need to be capitalized from "Mon to MON"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**i'm using the below format to show date with day of the week like "12/30/2015 - Mon". but need to show the day in capitalized form like "MON" *instead of* "Mon"**

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy - ddd}");
```

Comment: is it possible to change the localised strings to use capitalised day abbreviation?

Comment: else maybe using css with `text-transform: capitalise;`

Comment: @ Nikos .It's Happening, Thanks for you suggestion

Comment: great, which one worked?

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo datetime formatting [support](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting) has nothing to control the capitalisation of the output.

Probably the easiest way is to do this explicitly on the client.

In the grid set up:

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Width(100).ClientTemplate("#:formatUpcaseDate(Date)#");
```

and then in your JavaScript format and convert to upper-case:

```
function formatUpcaseDate(d) {
  return kendo.toString(d, 'MM/dd/yyyy - ddd').toLocaleUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your suggestion it's not happening. it shows the date with time format "12/30/2015 1:00:00 PM"

Comment: @Gopalakrishnanyadav It is quite possible I've got that `kendo.toString` call not quite right. Worth validating against the Kendo docs.